# Would questions about paper-planes be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If someone asks some questions on paper-planes and related items, would it be on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say yes.  They are airplanes (well, gliders to be specific).

Besides, if you have questions about how the basic mechanics of flight work, a paper airplane is a good way to learn them.  Not only that, but mechanics of flight is certainly within the scope of this site so, by extension, questions about paper airplanes should be fine.

We even [have a tag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-airplane) for it.  So, yeah.  Ask away :).

Comment: I would add that there is a beta stack exchange in which would be better to put the question if it is about how to make one https://crafts.stackexchange.com/